# unbind events that was bound to div coordinates

Tags: jquery

i'm using jquery to bind click and mousemove events to coordinates of the div:

```
$("#main").live("mousemove click", function(event) {
var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  if ( event.type == "mousemove" ) {
        if ( (x >= 607 && x <= 720) && (y >= 345 && y <= 390) ) {

            //cursor:pointer
        }
   }  else //do something on click
```

what i want to do is to clear this binded events after i ajax load new content to my main div.

thanks!

Comment: look into using jQuery.delegate() and jQuery.undelegate() instead.  jquery.delegate() is an alternative to live() and jQuery.undelegate will unbind the delegated events.

Comment: Do you mean you want to unbind the event, or zero out x and y?  It's not really clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to unbind the method attached with live() you have to use [die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/);

```
   $("#main").die()
```

taken from the docs

> Any handler that has been attached with .live() can be removed with
>   .die(). This method is analogous to calling .unbind() with no
>   arguments, which is used to remove all handlers attached with .bind().
>   See the discussions of .live() and .unbind() for further details.

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery documentation:

> To unbind the click handlers from all  that were
>   bound using 
>       .live(), use the .die() method:

```
$(".clickme").die("click");
```

Source:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

as live elements are attached to the body, you can use

```
$(document).unbind('mousemove click');
```

to unbind them too